# Datatable doesn't load JSON data, shows message "No data available in table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, shopify

I'm using Datatables.net to display data on my Shopify site. As an example, I just set the JSON data to have 1 key value pair of "itemcode" and then the actual product's item code. Here is an example of my data:

**JSON Data**

```
{
  "jsonData": [
    {
      "itemcode": "0735340080 - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "BL208-Z - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "9109K - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "735330016 - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "699-ZZ - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "698-ZZ - Bearings"
    },
    {
      "itemcode": "697-ZZ - Bearings"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this code to load the data in. To clarify, the JSON is loaded from a hidden div element on the page:

**Javascript Code**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonDataDiv = document.getElementById("json-data").innerText;
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonDataDiv);

    var table = $('#tableAppend').DataTable({
      orderCellsTop: true,
      pageLength: 25,
      data: jsonData,
      "columns": [{jsonData: "itemcode"}],
      columnDefs: [
        {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
      ],
    });    
});
```

No errors are reported in the debug window, but my table states that no data was available. My HTML code is here:

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="display" id="tableAppend" style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="dt-center">Item Code</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I've been following Q&A's online, but they don't seem to relate to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the initialization of the table

Check out https://codepen.io/mvinayakam/pen/abzpJar

$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonDataDiv = document.getElementById("json-data").innerText;
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonDataDiv);

```
var table = $('#tableAppend').DataTable({
  orderCellsTop: true,
  pageLength: 25,
  data: jsonData,
  "columns": [{data: "itemcode"}],
  columnDefs: [
    {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
  ],
});
```

})

As an aside, I am assuming the json is in the div only for trial purposes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I tried your code exactly and it still says no data available. The console does print out the JSON array object though so I know the data is correct.

Comment: Did you check the codepen link. It works for me there

Comment: I did. I copied your code exactly and it still says no data available. Considering it works in the codepen, I'm thinking something else is interfering with it, but I can't find out what.

Comment: Did you copy the html as well? Can you check all the components from the codepen

Answer (score 0):

You have to only change the data table column assign parameter name jsonData --> data

```
"columns": [{data: "itemcode"}],
```